# How to remove a number at end of a string if it is a single exam

Tags: php

Near the top of my script below the session_start(); I have this code below:

```
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

    $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];

    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['sessionNum'])){
                //Declare my counter for the first time

                $_SESSION['initial_session'] = $_SESSION['sessionNum'];
                $_SESSION['sessionNumber'] = intval($_SESSION['sessionNum']);
                $_SESSION['sessionCounting'] = 1;

        }

    elseif (isset($_POST['submitMarks']) && $_SESSION['sessionCounting'] < $_SESSION['sessionNumber']) {
        $_SESSION['sessionCounting']++;
    }

    $sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCounting'];
    $sessionConcat =  $_SESSION['sessionCounting'];


    if ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_session']){ 

        $action = 'infopenaltymarks.php'; 

    }elseif($sessionMinus != $_SESSION['initial_session']){ 

        $action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 

    }

$assessment = $_SESSION['id'] . $sessionConcat;
```

Now for the heading of the page I am using this code:

```
<h1>INDIVIDUAL MARKS FOR EACH ANSWER: ASSESSMENT (<?php echo $assessment ?>) <?php echo $sessionMinus ?> OF <?php echo $_SESSION['initial_session'] ?></h1>
```

Now lets say the `Session` Table in the database looks like this below:

```
SessionId  SessionName
1          AAA1
2          AAA2
3          AAB
```

Now if you look at the table above I have multiple exams `AAA1` and `AAA2` and I have a single exam `AAB`.

Now lets say I am working on Exam `AAA1`, it will display the heading as below:

> INDIVIDUAL MARKS FOR EACH ANSWER: ASSESSMENT (AAA1) 1 OF 2

The above heading is correct as it displays the correct exam name, and it states its the first out of the two `AAA` exams

When I submit the page, it will change the heading to go on the second `AAA` exam which is below:

> INDIVIDUAL MARKS FOR EACH ANSWER: ASSESSMENT (AAA2) 2 OF 2

Again the above heading is correct.

The problem I have is if I have a single exam, or in this case the exam `AAB`, as it is a single exam, it does not contain a number at the end of the exam name so it is simply displayed as `AAB` in the DB.

But when I output the heading it displays this below:

> INDIVIDUAL MARKS FOR EACH ANSWER: ASSESSMENT (AAB1) 1 OF 1

Now you can see that the above heading is incorrect as it is not exam `AAB1`, it should be `AAB` in between the brackets. So what my question is that if an exam is `1 OF 1` or in other words just a single exam, how can I remove the number 1 from the end of the exam name in between the brackets so it displays it as `AAB` and not `AAB1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the session count only if greater than 1

```
$assessment = $_SESSION['id'];
if ($_SESSION['initial_session'] > 1) {
    $assessment .= $sessionConcat;
}
```

Fix right before printing the line

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['initial_session'] == 1) {
    $assessment = substr($assessment, 0, -1);
}
?>
<h1>INDIVIDUAL MARKS FOR EACH ANSWER: ASSESSMENT (<?php echo $assessment ?>) <?php echo $sessionMinus ?> OF <?php echo $_SESSION['initial_session'] ?></h1>
```

Comment: $assessment is at the bottom of the top block of code in my question